# Verify if apps are fully compatible to the intended Android version upgrade

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, android-versions

I am on 4.4.2 and am toying with idea of upgrading to Marshmallow, mainly to use *doze* feature

I have 150+ apps and want to check how many of them are upgraded to work with Marshmallow, *before* upgrading (upgrading my device Huawei Honor 6 and rolling back is complicated and not fail proof)

**I am looking for a way to list all apps (on my device) and compare with Play Store information to know which/ how many apps are upgraded to API 23  to take a call, whether to upgrade or not**

Manual verification is an obvious way, which I don't want

Is there a way to achieve this? ( including app based )

Comment: My first thought was using `pm list packages -3` (results in a bunch of lines of the format `package:com.foobar.app`) and then … well, how will you tell whether the package "was upgrade to API 23", without grabbing the `.apk` and running some `aapt` stuff against it? I doubt even the playstore API will reveal enough details, though that might be worth checking.

Comment: I can't tell you about API availability in this context, nor do I know of existing solutions. So all I can offer is obtaining the package names in the hope those can be used for a solution (btw, the `-3` restricts the list to "3rd party apps", i.e. non-system apps).

Comment: There is no necessity for an app to be targeted or even upgraded specifically for Marshmallow to work with that Android version. *Doze is an app independent feature*. It will work to affect an app regardless whether the app is targeted at API level 23. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html): "*Doze and App Standby manage the behavior of all apps running on Android 6.0 or higher, regardless whether they are specifically targeting API level 23.*" // What objective are you trying to achieve by knowing which apps have been upgraded?

Comment: @Firelord: Thanks. That solves my concern, which was to test doze in marshmallow. I was under the impression that apps needed to be MM level to fully utilise doze. Huawei (also in kitkat) implements a doze like feature so wanted to see how it is implemented by them in MM. You can elaborate as an answer to close this.  I stated my intention in first line but guess it got missed out. Apart from that, it would be an interesting exercise to figure out , I guess, to view app by API in Play Store?

Comment: For the second part of viewing apps by API, if it is not possible, stating reasons would be good for someone else who refers to this in future that being his primary intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to list all apps (on my device) and compare with Play Store information to know which/ how many apps are upgraded to API 23 to take a call, whether to upgrade or not [to use doze feature.]

It would be interesting to have a solution for this, but it turned out that you don't have to bother about all of this when it comes to upgrading to Marshmallow. In the document [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), Google has noted:

> Doze and App Standby manage the behavior of all apps running on Android 6.0 or higher, **regardless whether they are specifically targeting API level 23**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>